# Is it legal to publish legal documents of Venice Commission on the own website

Tags: copyright, public-law

For research we are using official documents.
When official document publish as single PDF file or as regular web page it's difficult to hyperlink to a specific part of the document.

But our [technology stack](https://en.chitkyi-zakon.org/law/general.html#_technology_stack) make it easy, but we have to keep sources on our web site.

Here is an example of `EU Commission's Recommendations for Ukraine's EU candidate status` in our [website](https://en.chitkyi-zakon.org/law/eu-conditions-for-ukraine.html).
We always have link on our website to the original resource.

Could anyone justify how it is or is not legal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many official documents are protected by copyright. For those that are, making and posting such copies is infringement unless permission to do so has been granted by the relevant official entity.